# The output of numerical calculation of BCEWithLogitsLoss for PyTorch example

Tags: python, pytorch

When I looked the example code of BCEWithLogitsLoss in PyTorch Docs. I am confusing about the output result of loss function and formula.

[PyTorch Example](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html):

```
>>> loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
>>> input = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)
>>> target = torch.empty(3).random_(2)
>>> output = loss(input, target)
>>> output.backward()

input : tensor([0.4764, -2.4063,  0.1563], requires_grad=True)
target: tensor([0., 1., 1.])
output: tensor(1.3567, grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward>)
```

But according to the formula by showing:

[image]

The output of loss function should have shape (3,) instead of single value ,since the shape of input and output both are (3,) . I was thinking that the output may was the sum of Ln or else, but still no idea. Could someone help me to explain that?

As @Dishin H Goyani reminded that the default reduction is 'mean'. I did a simple test.

```
>>> target_n = target.numpy()
>>> input_n  = input.detach().numpy()
>>> def sigmoid(array):return 1/(1+np.exp(-array))
>>> output_n = -1*(target_n*np.log(sigmoid(input_n))+(1-target_n)*np.log(1-sigmoid(input_n)))
output_n : array([0.95947516, 2.4926252 , 0.61806685], dtype=float32)
>>> np.mean(output_n)
1.3567224
```

The result is matched.

As you seen, the default Wn is 1.

Comment: More specifically if you want no reduction use `reduction='none'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As *reduction* parameter **default** value is '**mean**' in BCEWithLogitsLoss.

The output is mean - the sum of the output will be divided by the number of elements in the output.

[Read Doc here for more detail:](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bcewithlogitsloss)
Parameters
...
**reduction** *(string, optional)* – Specifies the reduction to apply to the output: `'none'` | `'mean'` | `'sum'`.

> `'none'`: no reduction will be applied,
>   `'mean'`: the sum of the output will be divided by the number of elements in the output,
>   `'sum'`: the output will be summed.

Note: size_average and reduce are in the process of being deprecated, and in the meantime, specifying either of those two args will override reduction. Default: `'mean'`
...